# ¿Cómo comparo si un elemento de una lista en Python es una cadena (String)?

Tags: python, lista, string, comparaciones, pseudocódigo

Ejemplo:

```
lista = [2, 3.525, "unaCadena", 10000]


for i in lista:
    if lista[i] == Str():
        print(lista[i])
```

Lo que yo quiero es que me imprima unaCadena (es solo un ejemplo simplificado, obviamente)
¿Saben cómo hacer para identificar cadenas de alguna forma? Porque eso no me funciona... Gracias!

Comment: Recuerda siempre investigar e intentar primero. Cuando investigues intenta formular tu pregunta no de un modo particular sino mas general. El enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type que responde a la pregunta "¿Cómo determinar el tipo de una varable en Python?" te da la información que necesitas?

Comment: Si @MauricioOrtega eso me lo contesta, solo que está en Inglés y no lo busqué en Inglés, debe ser por eso que no me apareció. Mil Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas recorriendo mal la lista ya que le estas asignando a `i` los valores de la lista y no sus indices por lo que no puedes utilizar dentro del bucle `lista[i]` sino la misma variable `i`

```
for i in lista:
    if type(i) == str:
    print(i)
```

la otra opcion es asignarle la variable `i` a los **indices** de los elementos de la lista (**la cual consume menos recursos**) utilizando un rango == longitud de la lista `range( len(lista) )`

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    if type(lista[i]) == str:
    print(lista[i])
```

la funcion `type()` nos retorna y permite identificar el tipo de dato actual de la variable  : `int` , `float` , `str` , `bool`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Con el método `isintance()` puedes hacer eso donde el primer argumento es el objeto a comparar y el segundo es la clase a saber. ej:

```
for i in lista:
    if isintance(i,str):
        print(i)
```

> Cuando iteras una lista, es decir utilizas for en listas, la varible `i` es el elemento y no el indice.

Comment: Typo: es `isinstance` (falta la s).

Comment: Detalle adicional: isinstance devuelve verdadero para instancias de subclases (de str en este caso). Si este comportamiento no es el deseado, se puede preguntar si el tipo de la instancia es igual a str. type(i) == str

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(lista1)-1):
    if type(lista1[i]) == str:
        primera.append(lista1[i])
```

Gracias a todos por su colaboración! Pude hacerlo de la siguiente forma: Comparando con la función type() == str

Comment: Si no te ha quedado claro, el código de tu pregunta falla porque compara **2 objetos**. En la solución funciona porque compara **2 tipos**.